# Advice needed: Best practice when sharing LE wildcard certificate between multible web-services on the same host

Tags: docker, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I need your advice. What is the best way, from an opsec-perspective, when sharing an LE wildcard certificates between several web-services on the same host?

### My setup is like this:

- On my domain I have an auto-renewed LE wildcard cert (containerized)

  - The folder holding the certificates is mapped to a host folder, owned by LE-user:LE-group and has 700 privileges assigned
- All sub-domains are pointing to web-services on the same host (all containerized)
- All publicly accessible services are handled by an Nginx reverse proxy (containerized) and thus they are all LE SSL encrypted downstream
- The admin services (portainer, adminer, cockpit, etc.) are only accessible from the LAN and are all protected by strong and unique passwords

### My problem:

I want to protect the above-mentioned admin-services with the LE wildcard cert as I am tired of having to confirm that I "accept the risk" because they are using self-signed certs, but I'm in doubt what is the best way to achieve this.
So far I see three possible ways around it, all having their own drawbacks:

1. Create a script executed by a cron-job that copy the LE certificate to the various admin-services cert-folders whenever the cert is renewed.

   - **Drawback:** The script would need to be run with root privileges
2. Allow the admin-services to access the cert in the host-mapped folder.

   - **Drawback:** I would need 704 access to the LE Cert folder or 740 and add all admin-sevice-users to the LE group
3. Serve the admin-services through the reverse proxy, enable TOTP protection and restrict access to the public IP of the server.

   - **Drawback:** If I mess something up or there is a zero-day exploid in my Nginx or TOTP installation, the admin-services are publicly accessible

Which of the above mentioned solutions do you see as the "best-practice" solution from a opsec perspective or would you suggest a completely different solution that I haven't thought about?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

1. Create a legitimate local CA root cert with something like openssl.
2. With it, legitimately sign a server certificate that you'll use for admin-services and configure the Admin-Services SSL endpoint to use that.
3. Ensure your CA root cert is in the Trusted CA Certificates certificate store (aka Trust Store) of the machine with which you connect to admin-services.

A cert created in this way just has an non-trusted root CA until you explicitly trust it in the connecting-machine's trust store (i.e. Step #3). The added benefit now is that you can expire either cert when you want instead of every 3 months unlike an LE Wildcard cert.

Resource: https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After considering your suggestion I think it's the right solution. I was reluctant to go this route because I wouldn't want to to have to have to mark my own CA as trusted on all my devices but in the end I think this is the right solution. And after looking into it, it doesn't seem too hard either... Many thanks...